Does identity theory “solve” the hard problem of consciousness?
In identity theory, mental events just are certain physical events in the brain. The hard problem of consciousness is about how certain physical events give rise to certain mental events.
But isn’t this hard problem already biased against identity theory? If mental events just are certain physical events, there is no process of arising, hence the question is a non starter. A certain form of water does not give rise to it being a river. A certain structure of water is a river.

And that particular structure yields certain properties that other arrangements of water do not have (erosion, rapids, fresh water even while connected to an ocean, etc). The question is why it has those properties, not why it's called "river". For some reason, certain arrangements of mental events yield a first person experience. Whether those events cause that experience or are that experience, it doesn't yet answer the question of "why".

@Ray one can play the same game. There are certain properties physical things that correspond to mental events may have that others don’t (for example: the property of being chemical events in a brain like structure). The concept of a “river” and arguably properties is manmade. You’re assuming that there is a “why” in the first place. Why do you think there’s a “why”?

The concept of "river" might be man-made. The fact that erosion happens isn't. I'm not saying that identity theory is wrong, mind you (I'm quite fond of approaches that try to minimize mystical handwaving). Just that those particular sets of mental states yield specific observable effects, chief among them being a sense of self, and identity theory doesn't tell us why that is (nor does it purport to, as far as I know).

@Ray if A is identical to B, it makes no sense to ask why A is B. You would basically have to show that identity theory is wrong before asking why. Again, what is your evidence that there is a “why” in the first place?

I don't have an answer to that. I haven't solved the Hard Problem either. But that "why" is the Hard Problem, so for identity theory to have solved it, it needs to either answer it or demonstrate that it's a meaningless question, not just be compatible with the idea that it's a meaningless question. (And note that in the river example, we can answer all those "why"s, even though the river is just that arrangement of water.)

@Ray why should the burden of proof be on the person who thinks it is a meaningless question? If there is no further explanation to something, then the question is meaningless. At best, you could say we don’t even know if there is a hard problem. Perhaps my question can be rephrased as “does the hard problem of consciousness beg the question against identity theory?” In the river question, we don’t answer the question: “why is this form of water a river?” That question is meaningless

The burden is on anyone who claims to have solved the problem. If another theory claimed that it's not a meaningless question, it would have the burden to show that, too.

@Ray the hard problem of consciousness is a claim that there is a problem and that it is not a meaningless question though.

Then it can share the burden of proof.

When people say consciousness is a "hard" problem, they typically mean it's categorically different from "easy" problems that science investigates / solves, in that explaining the mechanisms behind it is not even possible in principle.
There may be at least a little circular reasoning (or merely a trivial rephrasing) going on here: if you already accept that dualism is "outside" of mechanical and physical things, of course that means we're not going to be able to explain the mechanics behind it (90% of dualists and 80% of non-physicalists say consciousness is a hard problem, although a majority consider it a hard problem even outside of that).
I wouldn't say identity theory (or reductive materialism) solves the hard problem of consciousness, but it seems reasonable enough to say calling it a hard problem denies identity theory. Because identity theory posits a mechanical explanation that one denies by calling it a hard problem.
Although someone might say even if we know which brain parts and state is correlated with which conscious experience (and even if we could recreate that in a lab), we still wouldn't know the mechanical reason for this. To this, I might respond: hi, and welcome to reality. That statement applies to everything we know about all of reality. We build models about reality based on correlations.
And... oh boy, do we have a lot of correlations between consciousness and the brain. If anything could be said to have refuted the hard problem of consciousness, it's probably that, instead. We've reduced so much of consciousness already. That's what the field of neuroscience does, in a nutshell. But people can still say, and may always be able to say, that there is still some irreducible part hidden within the 10s-of-billions of neurons and the over-100-trillion connections in the human brain... because that's just too complex to fully map. We have neither the processing power nor the imaging technology to fully model that, and maybe we never have that. Maybe we boil awareness down to some small section of the brain, which we can fully map and disprove that it's a hard problem. Or maybe awareness consists of too many components for us to provide a full map (it may be that, to be aware, one requires sensory experiences, and memory, and some sense of reasoning, and possibly emotion).
Calling it a "hard" problem is asserting that we'll never be able to solve that problem. Claims about what we will or won't know in future may be some of the least reliable and least justifiable claims. Although, as mentioned above, plenty of people may be inferring this from an existing presupposition of dualism (which may be a reasonable inference if dualism were justified, which I don't consider it to be).
Identity theory versus reductive materialism
In my opinion, reductive materialism has the misfortune of being used (e.g. on Wikipedia) as an alternative name for a far inferior and worse-supported idea that is type physicalism or identity theory.
A quote from Wikipedia:

Type physicalism is contrasted with token identity physicalism, which argues that mental events are unlikely to have "steady" or categorical biological correlates. These positions make use of the philosophical type–token distinction (e.g., Two persons having the same "type" of car need not mean that they share a "token", a single vehicle). Type physicalism can now be understood to argue that there is an identity between types (any mental type is identical with some physical type), whereas token identity physicalism says that every token mental state/event/property is identical to some brain state/event/property.

Simply put, this is not how we describe anything else in science.
If you consider the car analogy, 2 cars could be said to be identical if they consist of the exact same physical components (down to the atom). When you turn each of those cars on, you'd expect the same result. The result is often it's not identical because cars aren't identical down to the atom, and they're greatly affected by different environments (but even still, the behaviour of cars is exceedingly consistent). And you can swap out parts and still have the same behaviour. This could even include parts swapped out for parts with a completely different chemical makeup.
What we call the "type" of a car might broadly be considered the model (possibly including the year, possibly not), but that could include an extremely wide range of behaviours and parts. For some, the "type" of a car might be the manufacturer instead, which is much broader.
This isn't a particularly tenable way to describe cars (or much of anything else), never mind describing brains.
In reality, this "type" and "token" distinction is something we made up, and we classified objects into. Those things don't actually exist in reality. As I commonly say: reality doesn't fit neatly into the boxes made up by one species on a little rock in the middle of nowhere in particular.
Multiple realizability and the identity of indiscernibles is only a problem if you insist on a type-token distinction that objectively exists.
Reductive materialism, meanwhile, doesn't inherently make any type-token distinction. It is purely the idea that consciousness reduces to the parts of the brain. Like how every other physical system reduces to its parts. Identity theory is a mess that was added on top of that and it just makes the idea worse.
Related: my answer to Has reductive physicalism been falsified? (spoiler alert: no), where I break down what "reductive physicalism" means, and argue that it is, in fact, quite reasonable.


Other answers
Why does subjective experience accompany brain stuff?

why there should be a subjective experience accompanying brain stuff in the first place

Why should there be the movement of air accompanying lungs in the first place? Why should there be magnetic fields accompanying certain metals in the first place?
They aren't "accompanying" those things. Those things are just what they do and what they are.
We can model this at various scales. We can model how an individual neuron functions, and we can model how the whole brain works together, and how certain parts of the brain correspond to certain functions of consciousness. It's unclear if there's still some fundamental gap, in needing to explain where awareness comes from, if that's even a coherent question to ask, or if it's just incremental progress all the way through.
This is really much more of a problem for dualists (including epiphenomenalists and those positing strong emergence*).
* It's debatable whether those are physicalism. They are certainly dualism, and not physicalist monism (they can't sit with us!). Physicalist monism doesn't posit that there are multiple different "kinds" of substance (and also not different kinds of "properties", whatever that means) - there is only the physical. If someone wants to define multiple kinds of substances, it's their burden to differentiate those.
For dualists, subjective experience would be "accompanying" brain stuff, and it would need to do so exceedingly consistently to match the evidence. Consciousness exists in some undefined place that may not be a place ("non-physical"?). For every conscious organism, their consciousness magically pops into existence (or something) and gets "connected" to them at some undefined point during conception. When conscious experiences happen, we just so happen to be able to consistently see those in physical brain scans. When you suffer brain injury, illness or disease affecting a particular part of the brain, it just so happens that you lose the corresponding function of consciousness. Organisms with smaller brains just so happens to have more limited functions of consciousness, and all the way down to some really simple organisms, there doesn't seem to be any clear line we can draw that could reasonably separate conscious from non-conscious, except by the presence of neurons. Most models of dualism would predict that, at some point, consciousness shows up, and there'd be a significant behavioural difference without a corresponding physical difference... but we don't see that.
You have to come up with really contrived explanation to reject the obvious explanation that your brain is the thing that makes consciousness.
Can emergence be subject to natural selection?

Those who raise a probable evolutionary advantage for emergence of consciousness also miss the point that evolutionary gains are brought solely by natural selection

That only applies to strong emergence (which is dualism). Not weak emergence, i.e. reductive materialism.
For reductive materialism, the evolutionary explanation fits perfectly. Consciousness consists of many parts and every new function of consciousness corresponds to changes in the brain, which is subject to evolutionary pressure.
Cue the comments about how weak emergence is not "real" emergence. But that's what it's called, and arguing semantics is generally pointless. I'm merely pointing out, for the sake of clarity, that the above comment about "emergence" doesn't apply to the thing that is commonly called "weak emergence".
Do eliminative materialism say consciousness "doesn't exist"?

eliminationists ... say that consciousness doesn't actually exist, that is, it's an illusion, ... but the problem is they are denying the obvious and also undermining the basis of all human knowledge!

The sense in which eliminative materialism says things "don't exist" is that it doesn't exist in the way we understand it. Like how a mirage doesn't exist. If you see a mirage of an oasis in a desert, the oasis may not exist, but there may still exist some light bouncing off of things to cause what you're seeing. Or maybe there is actually some other object that just looked like an oasis. But it's also possible that the mirage is entirely imagined with no corresponding physical substance (i.e. a pure hallucination... or a dream).
Also, one can be "eliminative" about any or every part of consciousness. In it's most extreme form, it's that consciousness itself "doesn't exist" (i.e. we understand it incorrectly). But one may also say e.g. pain, doesn't exist in the way we imagine it.
So it's certainly not as extreme as the quote above imagines it, unless we take the most extreme version of the most extreme version of it (which could hardly be considered representative or accurate).
Although I don't consider eliminative materialism to be much of a hypothesis. It may be useful to note that we may be wrong about some of these things, but saying we're wrong doesn't tell you what's right. Eliminative materialists seem to typically argue for something close to reductive materialism: to the extent that consciousness exists, it reduces to brain activity.

I don't think it solves the problem, it just pushes it back a level.
The mechanism of awareness of self may simply be a mental model of self carried in the brain as we do models of the world around us, including our own bodies. (That happens to be my own belief.)
But that still leaves us with the problem of understanding where that model is in the brain, what it's parts are, and how it works to produce what we experience as consciousness.
The devil, and the self, is in the details.

The hard problem points to the subjective experience of consciousness which is a distinct experience and datum from brain and its activities, and then asks why there should be a subjective experience accompanying brain stuff in the first place.
This not only questions the identity theory, but type identity, epiphenomenalism and emergentism, i.e. the entire physicalist camp, for none can explain why there must be subjective experience in the first place and this includes emergentism too because just to assert that consciousness is an emergent property doesn't explain why should it emerge from matter in the first place!
Those who raise a probable evolutionary advantage for emergence of consciousness also miss the point that evolutionary gains are brought solely by natural selection (itself solely a physical process) and are ultimately embedded in the organisms' evolving physiology and anatomy. Therefore emergence of consciousness somewhere along the evolutionary process would be quite redundant and unnecessary because whatever function/gain is served by the subjective conscious experience must be realizable in the physiology. And this is still not to mention how a supposedly blind and unconscious process can generate consciousness ex nihilo.
The problem with identity theory however is doubelfold because it is also at odds with a logical principle: identity of indiscernibles and its opposite non-idenitity of discernibles, which says that if two things are identical then they must not be discernible one from the other at all, but we do discern the subjective experience from brain and its activities, in the sense that we get two sets of data which are different.
So eliminationists embark on a kind of epistemic suicide just to avoid the force of the feared dualist beast by saying that consciousness doesn't actually exist, that is, it's an illusion, just to avoid the hard problem, but the problem is they are denying the obvious and also undermining the basis of all human knowledge! As I have extensively argued elsewhere, illusion itself is rather a form and subcategory of consciousness, therefore illusion can't logically be predicated of consciousness in general, as illusion is only a possible property of conscious states (i.e. beliefs and images) not a property of consciousness in general. To rule consciousness in general an illusion is self-contradictory because it implies that everything we know is an illusion, including eliminationism and physicalism, and all, because we know everything by our consciousness.

A great answer until the last paragraph, which is just going to get people's hackles up instead of encouraging them to think through your excellent argument. I recommend deleting the last paragraph.

If the act of discerning itself requires consciousness, how do we know that the rule you mentioned applies here?

@Syed The rule applies because consciousness can discern itself from other things, as well as discerning things from others. Read another answer of mine where I explain the peculiar properties of consciousness: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/120898/5577

@DavidGudeman Thank you. I did as per your advice but some of my best written answers get downvoted to the bottom only because of not endorsing this dogma. Sometimes I think I'm just throwing gems to the pit on SE.

Short Answer
Yes.  Identity theory is a possible solution to the hard problem of consciousness.
And no, the hard problem is not biased against identity theory.
The problem for identity theory, is that every proposed identity, has failed test cases against it.  There are cases where we have consciousness when it is not predicted, or don't have consciousness when it is predicted we would.  As a predictive model, every variant of it has been falsified.  It is the observed properties of consciousness that lead to identity theories failing to answer the hard problem of consciousness.
Why identity theory could have been a solution
Empiricism operates off of incremental understanding. Many critics of Identity Theory point to its lack of an actual THEORY to explain consciousness, and merely asserting a 1:1 correlation.  BUT, in science, if one finds a 1:1 correlation, and this is predictively useful, then based on its predictive utility, we just accept that eh correlation is the way things are.  That is what Newton did with gravity as a property of mass. His Theory of Gravity actually lacks a theory of what CAUSES gravity, and so far, we are still stumped by that subsequent question.
So, there wasn't any going in reason to dismiss Identity Theory.
What are the refuting test cases for neural Identity Theory?
We have loads of examples of lack of "identity" between neurology and a consciousness state.
Most notably, introspection into our reasoning process was what we used to design our digital computers.  Yet there is nothing remotely like the reasoning process built into our neurology.  All our neurology is, instead, an analog neural net system -- and neural nets don't even have the equivalent of precepts, operants, etc. of our reasoning process.
If one postulates that a conscious experience is identical to a specific energizing event of a specific neural network, then one should be able to observe the same thought repeatedly whenever that excitation pattern happens in that neural network -- which we generally do not see.  The vast majority of the time, we are NOT conscious of the events in our neurology --so we see excitations all the time that don't produce any consciousness, much less that specific thought.
Of particular interest is the issue of multiple realizability.  Instead of the 1:1 prediction of Identity Theory, when we seem to have the same thought, we do so under multiple excitation patterns.  AND we see the same thought despite our neurology continually modifying itself.  AND we can transfer the same thought to another individual, in a successful memetic transfer.
So we see no thoughts when excitations happen to the same neurology, and the same thought in multiple different excitations, and in different necrologies.  Therefore, thoughts are NOT identical to a specific excitation pattern in a specific neurology.
What are the refuting test cases for functional Identity Theory
These failures of neural identity theory led most philosophers of mind to instead adopt functional identity theory -- that consciousness is identical to performing a function, which could be done under multiple neurologies, and activation patterns.
Once more, the issue was that consciousness did not behave as the theory predicted.  We humans actually do basically every function that we do consciously, also UNconsciously.  Therefore, no function is identical to being conscious.
Functionalists have attempted to narrow the range of functions that might be conscious.  Higher Order Processing postulates that only modeling functions that include the self as an element int he model are conscious.  Global Workspace Theory postulates that only information that is global to the full brain is conscious. Strange Loop Theory postulates that only functions that have logically recursive definitions are conscious.  IIT holds that only algorithms run in a very high Phi network are conscious.
All of these suffer from three problems -- first, we don't seem to actually "run algorithms" on our neural net.  Second, that we have unconsciousness during much of the proposed social state.  For instance: driving should be global, but we can basically drive [poorly] with our consciousness disengaged.  All of our "functions" are run on the same high Phi network, but 99.9% are not conscious, etc.  And third, we have mental experiences that don't satisfy these criteria. Staring at a fire and the play of flames and smoke does not engage either higher order processing, or a strange loop.
Finally, if one tries to say the identity is only occasional, rather than necessary, then the Evolutionary Test Case would lead to consciousness decoupling from relevance to the world.
Summary
Identity Theory in principle could have solved the hard problem of consciousness, but the actual nature of consciousness involves one refutation of Identity Theory after another.

One approach is to unify identity theory with panpsychism.
Under panpsychism, everything is a mental event; the motion of one electron is a mental event. So of course, the physical events in the brain are also mental events, and vice versa. Or more precisely, to call an event "physical" is nothing more than to look at it from a certain perspective.
The same object can have different appearances when viewed from different perspectives. The human brain looks pink, when viewed with the naked eye. It has a different apparent shape when you look at it from the top compared to the bottom. It looks like a branching web, when viewed through a microscope. It looks like a squiggly black-and-white graph, when viewed through an EEG. Each instrument you use to view the brain results in a different appearance, coming out of the instrument. Every physical variable - force, mass, velocity - is nothing more than an appearance through a certain type of instrument.
Consciousness, then, is what the brain (or, more accurately, a particular subsystem of the brain) looks like "from the inside"; when viewed through itself.
The hard problem of consciousness, in this setting, is to explain why the brain looks like that when viewed through itself, and how to relate that "inside" appearance to the appearance of the brain when viewed through cameras or EEGs or other instruments used in neurology.
The answer to this "why" would involve mathematical formulas relating the inside appearance to various outside appearances (force, mass, energy, entropy, etc).

The problem of identity theories is the vagueness as to how exactly a physical state is supposed to be identical to what type of conscious experience. For instance, there is nothing in quantum mechanics that tells us that quantum state X is identical to conscious experience Y. Same for general relativity. Same for string theory. Etc.

I feel as if the moment you separate physical events and conscious events, you are already begging the question against identity theory by considering them separate

@Syed What is it like to be a bat according to quantum  mechanics?

identity theory doesn’t say that we already know what physical states correspond to conscious states, just that they do. However, arguably, the more we learn about the brain, the more we find out that certain brain events do seem to correspond to certain kinds of conscious events. I don’t think this process being incomplete should serve as a defect. We just need to learn more

@Syed "However, arguably, the more we learn about the brain, the more we find out that certain brain events do seem to correspond to certain kinds of conscious events" - For example?

@Syed Have a look at Is the phenomenom of “subjective consciousness” or “qualia” formally captured by any state-of-the-art Theoretical Model in Physics?

@user80226 |ψ> = 1/√2|> + 1/√2|>

This is a good, if brief answer. Why would anyone downvote it? I'm wondering if we have once again picked up those forum lice who take a dislike to someone and start downvoting all of their posts. We had this problem before a moderator cleared it up, but think I'm starting to see it come back on my own posts, although not as obvious as before.

@DavidGudeman you unfortunately cannot prevent people from downvoting posts from users that are disliked. I personally didn’t downvote this answer but me and him are pretty disliked on here

The biggest problem with "identity" in philosophical understanding, is that it is not limited to a particular individual with a physical brain. Almost all great thinkers recognized the impossibility of a materialistic understanding of our "identity". And the main reason is the inheritance and footprint of previous generations (our family lineage) we carry in our "identity". If your ancestors were hunting in the jungle just 4–5 generations back, or if your ancestors were writing books in European cities 20 generations back, leaves a huge difference on who you are and what your "identity" is. Genetics cannot even start to explain those differences in our "identity".
